# Avoiding the close button on a popupKeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, popupwindow, soft-keyboard

I'm developing an IME for android. When a key is long pressed I can activate a popupKeyboard with the contents of variations of the key pressed (for instance with accents for vowels). By default the popupKeyboard contains a close button. Is there a way to avoid that button using the standard KeyboardView?

Thanks